# what is the main reason of not working the pressing remove button won't remove the item while pressing remove button won't remove the item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i am trying to make a todo list in reacthook. my App.js:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import AddTodo from './TodoFiles/AddTodo'
import TodoList from './TodoFiles/TodoList'

const defaultItems=[
  {id:1,title:'Write React Todo Project',completed:true},
  {id:2,title:'Upload it to github', completed:false}
]
const App=()=>{
  const [items,setItems]=useState(defaultItems)
  return(
    <div style={{width:400}}>
      <AddTodo items={items} setItems={setItems}/>
      <br/>
      <hr/>
      <TodoList items={items}/>
      <hr/>

    </div>
  )

}
export default App;
```

the addTodo.js is:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

const AddTodo=({items,setItems})=>{
    const[title,setTitle]=useState('')
    const handleTitle=(event)=>{
        setTitle(event.target.value)
    }
    const handleAddTodo=()=>{
        const NewItem={title}
        setItems([NewItem,...items])
    }
    return(
        <form onSubmit={e=>{e.preventDefault();handleAddTodo()}}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter new task..." style={{width:350,height:15}} 
     value={title} onChange={handleTitle}/>
            <input type="submit" style={{float:'right', marginTop:2}}/>
        </form>
    )
}

export default AddTodo
```

TodoList.js is:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const TodoItem = ({ title, completed, completeTodo, removeTodo, index }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: 400, height: 25 }}>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={completed} />
      {title}
      <button style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={() => completeTodo(index)}>
        Complete
      </button>
      <button style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={removeTodo}>
        Remove
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
const TodoList = ({ items = [], index }) => {
  const [, setItems] = useState("");
  const completeTodo = index => {
    console.log(index);
    const newItem = [...items];
    newItem[index].completed = true;
    setItems(newItem);
  };
  const removeTodo = index => {
    setItems(items.filter((p,index)=>p.index!==index))
  };

  return items.map((p, index) => (
    <TodoItem
      {...p}
      key={p.id}
      index={index}
      completeTodo={completeTodo}
      removeTodo={removeTodo}
    />
  ));
};

export default TodoList;
```

CompeleteTodo has been resolved but when i press the remove button it is not working and nothing has been deleted. there is no error while executing npm start. developer tools showing a warning:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
    in input (at TodoList.js:6)
    in div (at TodoList.js:5)
    in TodoItem (at TodoList.js:30)
    in TodoList (at App.js:18)
    in div (at App.js:13)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
```

what more i can to to fix it?

Comment: instead of splice you can do this: `const newItem= items.filter((_,idx) => index !== idx)`

Comment: and in **completeTodo** you can use map: `const newItem = items.map((item,idx) => index === idx ? ({...item, completed: true }) : item)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't set index in parameter of your function, simply you can do this:

```
const TodoItem = ({ title, completed, completeTodo, removeTodo, index }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: 400, height: 25 }}>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={completed} />
      {title}
      <button style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={() => completeTodo(index)}>
        Remove
      </button>
      <button style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={removeTodo}>
        Complete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
const TodoList = ({ items = [], index }) => {
  const [, setItems] = useState("");
  const completeTodo = index => {
    console.log(index);
    const newItem = [...items];
    newItem[index].completed = true;
    setItems(newItem);
  };
  const removeTodo = index => {
    const newItem = [...items];
    newItem.splice(index, 1);
    setItems(newItem);
  };

  return items.map((p, index) => (
    <TodoItem
      {...p}
      key={p.id}
      index={index}
      completeTodo={completeTodo}
      removeTodo={removeTodo}
    />
  ));
};

export default TodoList;
```

and your remove and complete function is upside down :)

[Check this](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-wood-i41td)

Comment: yap, i did a wrong with complete and remove...but the code still not working. i saw developer tools. it is saying "Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
    in input (at TodoList.js:7)
    in div (at TodoList.js:6)
    in TodoItem (at TodoList.js:29)
    in TodoList (at App.js:18)
    in div (at App.js:13)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)"

Comment: @ali, I think you not working in your mind is items not changed.this is because you changed them in child component and you have to change them in your parent component where you declare it.

Comment: oh man....i didn't pay attention...now completeTodo is working.... but remove is not still working.... do you know where i made it wrong?

Comment: Update your question, plz.

Comment: first of all you don't pass `index` to your remove function. then I said you have to change state in your parent component.

Comment: If it is useful don't forget up vote and accept answer, tnx

Answer (score 1):

here is my suggestion > implement remove-complete functional with array items id and not index of elements.

---

please read this [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

---

Here is [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-frog-82vk5)

> App

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import AddTodo from "./TodoFiles/AddTodo";
import TodoList from "./TodoFiles/TodoList";

const defaultItems = [
  { id: 1, title: "Write React Todo Project", completed: true },
  { id: 2, title: "Upload it to github", completed: false }
];
const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(defaultItems);
  return (
    <div style={{ width: 400 }}>
      <AddTodo items={items} setItems={setItems} />
      <br />
      <hr />
      <TodoList items={items} setItems={setItems} />
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

> AddTodo

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const AddTodo = ({ items, setItems }) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const handleTitle = event => {
    setTitle(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleAddTodo = () => {
    const newItem = [
      {
        id: Math.max(...items.map(x => x.id), 0) + 1
        completed: false,
        title
      },
      ...items
    ];
    setItems(newItem);
  };
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        handleAddTodo();
      }}
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="enter new task..."
        style={{ width: 350, height: 15 }}
        value={title}
        onChange={handleTitle}
      />
      <input type="submit" style={{ float: "right", marginTop: 2 }} />
    </form>
  );
};

export default AddTodo;
```

> TodoList

```
import React from "react";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";

const TodoList = ({ items, setItems }) => {
  const completeTodo = id => {
    setItems(
      items.map(item => (item.id === id ? { ...item, completed: true } : item))
    );
  };
  const removeTodo = id => {
    setItems(items.filter(p => p.id !== id));
  };

  return items.map(p => (
    <TodoItem
      {...p}
      key={p.id}
      completeTodo={completeTodo}
      removeTodo={removeTodo}
    />
  ));
};

export default TodoList;
```

TodoItem

```
import React from "react";

const TodoItem = ({ id, title, completed, completeTodo, removeTodo }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: 400, height: 25 }}>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={completed} onChange={() => {}} />
      {title}
      <button style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={() => completeTodo(id)}>
        Complete
      </button>
      <button style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={() => removeTodo(id)}>
        Remove
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoItem;
```